# SPARQL - merge all values based on a specific predicate

Tags: sparql

I have a predicate called **rdfs**: label and I would like to be able to return or merge all object values for this such that my results would look like this:

```
---------------------------------
       Value
---------------------------------

value 1, value 2, value 3, value 4
```

Comment: In reading the answer to the duplicate question, be sure to use `(group_concat(?label, separator=", ") as ?values)` (specifying the separator as `", "`, like [scotthenninger did](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35514023/1281433).

Answer (score 1):

Try SPARQL GROUP_CONCAT, e.g.:

```
SELECT (GROUP_CONCAT(?values; separator=", ") as ?value)
```